# Large buffer sizes plays, small size doesn't

Tags: c++, c, alsa

I'm having a problem getting sound output when I have a small buffer size (1920 frames). If I sample at `48kHz` and make the buffer size `480000` the sine wave plays correctly for 1 second. What I want to do it only play the sine wave for `40ms`.

I've calculate that to be `48000 samples/sec * 1sec/1000ms * 40ms = 1920 frames`. However, when I try to call `snd_pcm_writei` with only 1920 frames nothing comes out!

Here's the code in question:

```
void PCM::playSound(float freqHz, uint16_t durationMs)
{ 
    int FRAMES_LEN=48000;

    //Send the sine_buffer to sound card, with correct buffer length
    snd_pcm_sframes_t frames = snd_pcm_writei(handle, sine_buffer, FRAMES_LEN);

    if (frames < 0){
        HW_INFO() << "PCM::playSound-- snd_pcm_writei failed,trying to recover:" 
                  << snd_strerror(frames);
        frames = snd_pcm_recover(handle, frames, 0);
    }
    if (frames < 0) {
        HW_INFO() << "PCM::playSound-- snd_pcm_writei recovery failed: " 
                  << snd_strerror(frames);
    }
    HW_INFO() << "Wrote " << frames << " frames";

    return;
}
```

If `FRAMES_LEN` is `48000`, this code works fine and produces a sine wave that last 1 second.

If `FRAMES_LEN` is `1920`, I cannot hear a sine wave at all, but the log states that `Wrote 1920 frames`.

What is happening?

Comment: 40 ms is an incredibly short time and you would at most hear a pop or click.

Comment: I still don't hear anything with a 250ms duration, so 12,000 frames

Comment: Try decreasing the FRAMES_LEN from 48,000 down to 2,000 or so in decrements of perhaps 2,000 and see when you stop hearing what is produced.

Comment: Can you attach an oscilloscope to the output instead of the speaker and measure the partial sound wave that comes out?

Comment: What is the period size? Are you ever calling `snd_pcm_drain()`?

Comment: See this for a discussion of perceptible sounds as it relates to frequency and duration. http://sound.stackexchange.com/q/28163

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonable if there is any kind of post-processing going on with a filter of length >= 1920 frames. Such filtering can drop any click sounds, for instance. The whole reason for using ALSA instead of just talking to a D/A converter is to have audio-specific processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your logging is not lying to you. You asked it to write 1920 samples to the device and it did. Since your 48000 sample experiment played a sound that lasted for one second, your hardware must be running at 48 kHz. Assuming that, 1920 frames would last four hundredths of a second. Depending on the frequency of the sine in your sine buffer, you may not hear that.

Here's a deeper discussion: https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/28163